# Unable to pass `MuiLink` a React Router Link component in theme

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router, material-ui

The MUI docs state that if you want to use MuiLink as the component, but use the routing functionality of React Router, you should add it as a [Global theme link](https://mui.com/material-ui/guides/routing/#global-theme-link) in your theme.

The suggested example:

```
import * as React from 'react'
import type { LinkProps as RouterLinkProps } from 'react-router-dom'
import { Link as RouterLink } from 'react-router-dom'
import type { Components } from '@mui/material/styles'

const LinkBehavior = React.forwardRef<any, Omit<RouterLinkProps, 'to'> & { href: RouterLinkProps['to'] }>((props, ref) => {
  const { href, ...other } = props
  // Map href (MUI) -> to (react-router)
  return <RouterLink data-testid='custom-link' ref={ref} to={href} {...other} />
})

const theme = createTheme({
  components: {
    MuiLink: {
      defaultProps: {
        component: LinkBehavior,
      },
    }
  }
}
```

throws a type error:

```
Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'component' does not exist in type 'Partial<LinkProps<"a", {}>>'
```

Answer (score 1):

It turns out you have to cast the `defaultProps` object inside `MuiLink` in the theme:

```
import type { LinkProps } from '@mui/material'
...

const theme = createTheme({
  components: {
    MuiLink: {
      defaultProps: {
        component: LinkBehavior,
      },
    } as LinkProps
  }
}
```

[MUI source code](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/blob/cc113759330f3b8b269811d0e754bb0329b70197/docs/data/material/guides/routing/LinkRouterWithTheme.tsx#L36)